# Using backticks instead of apostrophes

Tags: sql, backticks

I am participating in an online program to become a data analyst. I am using SQL to construct queries along with the instruction videos. I feel there is no consistency using SQL regarding the use of backticks and apostrophes. When should I use backticks while constructing SQL queries, and when should I use apostrophes? Any help you can provide me is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Greg

Comment: Backticks are proprietary MySql syntax to delimit object (table, column) names. Single quotes are used to delimit string literals.

Answer (score 0):

Backticks are typically used by *MySql* as delimiters for using reserved words or names containing special characters such as a space. Most other platforms support "double quotes" as identifiers or also have their own proprietary syntax.

`'` single *quotes* are used to define `'string literal'` values in almost all database platforms.